# How to obtain a credential from user logged from oauth to, for example, describe instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, go, oauth, authorization

I like to obtain authorization from the user logged by oauth.
For example if a write a code that describe all instances, the awsuser A could describe only instance A (accoirding to policy in aws for awsuser A). And maybe, the awsuser B could describe more (according his policy in AWS, he has more permissions).

I don't want to put a service account and then write the authorization from my code, I prefer to use from the user in AWS.

I try libraries like goth, but I can't obtain credentials from AWS user logged.

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What specific error or other problem did you encounter/

Comment: To start coding, I have first done a research exercise to find out which library to use for authentication. But I can't find any library that once authenticated (by oauth) can obtain the user's credentials to use in the AWS library. Everything I find uses credentials passed by env or config to the software, it is not dynamic based on the authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you are trying to achieve, but I assume that you want to give users rights to describe EC2 Instances. So User A can only describe EC2-Instance-A and User B can only describe EC2-Instance-B.

I also assume that you want to use AWS API directly, as you mention "describe".
The solution looks like this: Use API Gateway to expose the AWS API that is needed for your use case; then use AWS Cognito to only allows the users to the API.

- [Secure API Gateway with Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-custom-scopes-api-gateway/)
- [Expose AWS Service via API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-aws-proxy.html)

Note that you might need different endpoints for the use cases or a lambda for the specific Instance Restriction (User A = Instance A; User B = Instance B). Maybe tags could help here.

---

Another solution is AWS IAM Identity Center, which allows you to federate users from a third party ("oauth") to assume a specific role in an AWS account. The IAM role can be configured to allow only the actions you described. This is more complicated as the solution above.